# WPF XAML How to write a trigger or multitrigger for datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, triggers, multitrigger

1 if you select the cell, set row background on a white colour

and

2 if you select the cell and row background is yellow, does not change the row background

I write this code for first condition, but I don't know how to make for first and second conditions together. Maybe I need a MultiTrigger ? :

```
                                <DataGrid.Resources>
                                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                                            Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                                            Value="White" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                            Value="Black" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>

                                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: I guess you are setting backgroud to `White` since you have overriden `HighlightBrushKey` to `Transparent` and selecting cell hides the cell content. So, setting ForeGround to Black i guess is sufficient there. That ways you don't have to worry about not updating background of cell with background yellow already.

Comment: It's true. This is a detail, but nevertheless would like to find solution this problem.

Comment: Added an answer with the solution. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are setting background to `White` since you have overriden `HighlightBrushKey` to Transparent and selecting cell hides the cell content. So, setting Foreground to Black i guess is sufficient there. That ways you don't have to worry about not updating background of cell with background yellow already.

---

But, however still you want to do that, you can do that using single `MultiDataTrigger` where you need to check if background of dataGridRow is Yellow, then do nothing. But since you want to do that unless background is Yellow color, **use [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if background is other than Yellow**.

```
<local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
//Declare local namespace with converter namespace in XAML

<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
  <Style.Triggers>
     <MultiDataTrigger>
       <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding Background,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType=DataGridRow},
                     Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
                     Value="False"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
      </MultiDataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and converter will be:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow.Equals(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```